# How to present an Integer representation to a Neural Network?

Tags: neural-network, training-data

I want to train a NN with details about parts that make up an entire product, and part of that data is the part ID that I receive as a unique integer ID; how would I go about inputting that to the NN? I don't want to normalize it as I don't want to put it on a common scale as it's not a scalar value; the number represents something.  Do I just input it as the raw number?

Comment: you can still normalize it. It doesn't lose its meaning. For example, if you have an input that can be 0,1, 2 or 3 (a number represents a state, not an actual value), when normalised, the input can be 0, 0.33, 0.66 or 1, but it still represent a state, not an actual value. (0 is state 0, 0.33 state 1 and so on...)

Comment: and you should ask your question here : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should have an input unit for each different part_id you have, that looks similar to what happens when you train networks to process language and you assign each word to a unit.

Answer (score 0):

One way to encode this is as a vector of booleans/integers. If the part with part id `x` exists, then `vec[x] = 1`, otherwise it is 0.

On the output side, it can be a vector of probabilities that that part exists.

Alternatively, you can use the number of times that part appeared rather than a simple exists vs not exists.